# PHP - Merge Two Functions

Tags: php, function, merge

I need to merge the following two functions, but I can't seem to get the syntax right:

One:

```
<?php= time() > strtotime( $var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hub_expiry-date', true) ) ? 'expired' : '' ?>
```

Two:

```
<?php
$var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hub_expiry-date', true); if ($var == '') { echo ""; } else { echo 'expired'; }
?>
```

What is the correct way of merging these?

Thanks
Zach

Comment: Just a note on the terminology: those are not functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hub_expiry-date', true);
if ( !empty($var) && time() > strtotime($var) ) {
    echo 'expired';
}
?>
```